# Is melting aluminium in the presence of carbon dioxide desirable?

Tags: metallurgy

So aluminium cans melting is prone to formation of aluminium oxide due to presence of oxgygen and thin sheet of aluminium (large surface area). To mitigate this I can design a cruicible which is filled with $\ce{CO2}$ from bottom so it displaces air before the start of melting process as well as a check valve to eliminate fumes and built up of pressure while heating.

**Question**: Will this process be successful in mitigating formation of aluminium oxide? I know in argon welding, they keep purging argon on the welding area (dynamic seal) to prevent formation of oxide, but in case of aluminium, will $\ce{CO2}$ suffice? Also is there any cheaper alternative?

Comment: This idea seems reasonable

Comment: Press the cans into a solid block and you don´t have to worry about air. But why do you want to do this? There are large aluminium recycling factories, and they do this *far more* energy-efficient than you, simply because of their size advantage.

Comment: @Karl Makes sense, so maybe use hydraulic press and press all the cans into a blob right? Also to answer your question, hobby and DIY stuff.

Comment: Al can react with CO2 to displace carbon, but at the comparatively low MP of Al, I don't know how rapidly. Just prevent rapid air exchange in the crucible, and the small amount of O2 in air will be quickly removed, leaving an Ar/N2 atmosphere.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium_recycling just in case ... ;)

Comment: @DrMoishePippik, makes sense. I guess formation of small alumina is inevitable in kitchen chemistry, its just a matter of knowing how much is called significant to render the process useless. The crucible will have a lid and a check valve so no air would enter and potentially all the gases produced from the coatings on the can as well as added $\ce{CO_2}$ will be purged out through the valve when temperature is gradually increased. I dont know if this is a recipe for disaster so any valuable input is greatly appreciated.